# Vertex cover in bipartite graphs with bounds on cost and size

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose we have a bipartite graph $G$ with non-negative integer vertex costs. We would like to find a vertex cover of cost at most $C$ and size (number of vertices) at most $S$, where $C$ and $S$ are given as part of the input.

Is this something that can be done in polynomial time? I assume that costs are given in binary, but I don't know the answer even if they are given in unary.